# Docker run entrypoint flags

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have a base image I cannot modify in this case. The entrypoint of the image is python3, but I have a docker run in which I would like to make /bin/bash the entrypoint. The point is, I want to put the -c and -l flags in the /bin/bash command.

To clarify, I would like the equivalent of
`ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash", "-l", "-c"]`
but when I run the `docker run --entrypoint /bin/bash <image>` command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're only looking to do this once, then you can override the entrypoint with the `--entrypoint` flag when using `docker run`.

```
$ docker run --entrypoint /bin/bash <image> -l -c
```

Everything that comes after the image name is passed to the new entrypoint as arguments.

Alternatively, if you expect you will be doing this again, I would instead recommend either:

1. Creating a new image altogether with `docker commit`:

   ```
   $ docker run -d <image>
   89373736
   $ docker commit --change='ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash", "-l", "-c"]' 89373736 mynewimage
   ```
2. Writing a custom Dockerfile:

   ```
   FROM <image>
   ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash", "-l", "-c"]
   ```

   and then build it:

   ```
   docker build -t mynewimage .
   ```

You will end up with a new image (`mynewimage`) that has the desired entrypoint.

Comment: Writing a custom Dockerfile would be preferable to `docker commit`.

Comment: @davidmade good point, thanks. I've added that too

Answer (score 1):

If you can't extend the image, you can achieve that by setting `/bin/bash` as the entrypoint and then passing the rest of the arguments as arguments to the container.

E.G:

```bash
docker run --entrypoint /bin/bash ubuntu -c ls
```

Runs `ls` inside your container. `docker run` does not accept sentences surrounded with quotes as it would try to find the executable named `/bin/bash -c -l` and would fail. So you're left with that or setting up a custom entrypoint script.